# F# how to handle nullable types

Tags: f#

I try to do some graphs in F#. As an input I have CSV file that has some values nullable (e.g. nullable int). I try to show chart with following code :

```
[for row in data.Rows -> row.A.Value, row.B.Value] |> Chart.Point
```

Where both A and B are nullable integers. I received following error

> System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.

How I should handle nullable types. Should I write some Option type to handle it or there is some other good way how to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where you are going wrong is: you are calling the `Value` property on something that might be null.

When you call `Value` you are effectively saying "It's okay, I have rigorously changed this value and it's *definitely not null* so it's perfectly safe to treat it as if it were a non-nullable value."  Of course, in this case, that condition isn't met, hence the runtime exception.

In F#, you don't want to be working with `Nullable<'T>` types, you want to be working with `Option<'T>`, this is much safer and the compiler can check more effectively that you're not making a mistake.

You can convert from `Nullable<'T>` to `Option<'T>` for the list using

```
[for row in data.Rows -> Option.ofNullable (row.A), Option.ofNullable(row.B)]
```

Of course then you have to decide how you want to handle the `None` cases but it's much easier to do that once you've made your design explicitly tell you that you've got a value that may or may not be something.

I don't know what behaviour you want but, as an example, perhaps you want to only chart the cases where both values are valid?

You could zip two option values:

```
module Option =
    let zip a b =
        match (a,b) with
        |Some sa, Some sb -> Some(sa, sb)
        |_ -> None
```

You can then map back to plotable numbers, extracting the `None` cases using `List.choose`.

```
[for row in data.Rows -> Option.ofNullable (row.A), Option.ofNullable (row.B)]
|> List.choose (fun (a,b) -> Option.zip a b)
|> Chart.Point
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using F# 4.0, then there is a built-in function `Option.ofNullable`. If no, then you can use the implementation in the other answer.

You can also use the same code to define an active pattern:

```
let (|Present|_|) (n:System.Nullable<_>) = 
  if n.HasValue then Some(n.Value)
  else None
```

... this can be used inside a `match` construct and so you can write:

```
[ for row in data.Rows do
    match row.A, row.B wih
    | Present a, Present b -> yield a,b 
    | _ -> () ] |> Chart.Point
```

Answer (score 2):

Map the Nullable type to Option type and filter them out (with .filter or .choose) or transform the None's to a special value for missing values (e.g. 0, -1, NaN) depending on your data to make them working in the charting tool.

```
module Option =
   let fromNullable (n: _ Nullable) =
       if n.HasValue
       then Some n.Value
       else None
```

Comment: doesn't Option.ofNullable already exist?